# can java 8 lambdas cause memory leaks?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, lambda

well I found this code in a [blog](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/11/10/beware-of-functional-programming-in-java/), and wanted to understand why it would cause a memory leak, if it is potential of causing a memory leak.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new EnterpriseBean()
            .runnable();
        runnable.run(); // Breakpoint here
    }
}

@ImportantDeclaration
@NoMoreXML({
    @CoolNewValidationStuff("Annotations"),
    @CoolNewValidationStuff("Rock")
})
class EnterpriseBean {
    Object[] enterpriseStateObject = 
        new Object[100_000_000];

    Runnable runnable() {
        return () -> {
            System.out.println("Hello from: " + this);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You got a link to this said blog?

Comment: added the link @dube

Comment: I am not so sure on how garbage collection works in java so any help would be great :)

Comment: The link explains it very well.

Comment: It's not a memory leak. It's accidental retention. And it could have happened before lambdas with inner classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The provided code does not have a memory leak, and the blog entry from which it is drawn does not say otherwise.  What it says is that the object returned by `EnterpriseBean.runnable()` has much (*much*) larger state than you might naively expect, and that that state cannot be garbage collected before the `Runnable` itself is.

However, there is nothing in that code that would prevent the `Runnable` from eventually being collected, and at that time all the extra state will be eligible for collection, too.

So no, the code is not an example of a memory leak, and does not suggest a means to produce one.